# How to solve the problem that docker cannot start on Intellij Utilmate on Windows 10 home? The docker service is on

Tags: docker, intellij-idea

[I'm using Docker on Itellij ultimate on Windows 10 home, however I met this problem when using command docker ps. Can any one tell me how to solve this problem?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQGZY.png)

Answer (score 0):

`docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified` is a general connectivity error to the service. Most likely related to the desktop app not being running. So make sure it's in the tray icon up and running, otherwise restart it. Otherwise, check the firewall and antivirus for any block rules.